# Get django user session objects from user email/id

Tags: django, django-sessions

How to get django user session objects from user id or email?

I am stuck with a problem for a particular user, he gets logged out from the system very frequently. I need to get the list of session objects for a particular user.

Comment: Seems its not possible. 
We may have to add **django-user-sessions** package to make it work. (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-sessions)

Comment: It is not possible to access django user session unless you have **django-user-sessions** package installed. It makes django session objects as first class citizens so that it can iterate session objects and gives you the user session objects. 

Note: I didn't add the above comment as answer. I haven't tried using that package. so can't comment on it if it really works.

Answer (score 2):

Session object is accessible by session_key, which is random string. It's generated on server side and stored in client side in Cookie. So it's impossible to identify user by session.